# Which male units will pass Pegasus Knight as an available class to their daughters?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

A child's available classes depends on their class, as well as those of their parents. Which male units will pass Pegasus Knight as an available class to their daughters (if they have a daughter)?

Comment: As pegasus knight is a female only class I do not believe it is inheritable from the father. The exception being your Avatar which will pass all non gender specific classes to your son/daugher.

Comment: Tharja can't be Pegasus Knight, but I'm pretty sure that if I marry her to the right fella that I can get her daughter to have Pegasus Knight.

Comment: Upon talking with a friend I think if the father has male only classes (fighter/barbarian) he will pass down female only classes to the daughter (peg knight/trubador).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A father that has access to male-only classes (Fighter and Barbarian) will pass on a female-only class instead. A father with access to Fighter will pass on Pegasus Knight to their daughter and a father with access to Barbarian passes on Troubadour. The exception to this is Vaike, who for some reason, despite having access to both Fighter and Barbarian, gives Knight and Mercenary to daughters instead. Guess he has something against mounts?

So, Gaius, Donnel, and a male Avatar will pass on Pegasus Knight to a daughter. If you're looking just to pass on the Pegasus Knight skills, a number of male children can get those from their mother - though male child characters whose mothers don't have access to Pegasus Knight will never be able to acquire Pegasus Knight skills.

Source: http://serenesforest.net/fe13/children.html